# update listView without using swapCursor()

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I want to update ListView that loads the user dictionary content provider using simpleCursorAdapter. I found a solution by,

```
Cursor newCursor = getContentResolver().query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
simpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
simpleCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

However the above solution queries the ContentResolver every time i want to update the list.

Is there a better solution that this?

Comment: how would you update the content of the list if you are not going to requery different data?

Answer (score 0):

Store it in an array if you dont want to requery, and extend a BaseAdapter and manually control how you get, when you get the data, and how you display it from the db.